# Kendu Menu from XML in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: xml, model-view-controller, kendo-ui, menu

I have XML datasource, need to create Kendo menu using ASP.NET MVC.  Please help!

Dnyanesh

Comment: Please post some code, and an example of the XML so it is easier to help you. And what bug/error do you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the only way you can achieve a dynamically generated Kendo UI Menu widget is to initialize it using a Kendo DataSource. You can bind arrays of JavaScript objects or remote XML, JSON, JSONP data to a DataSource and then initialize the Kendo UI Menu dynamically.

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/D54eM/

Here is an example of what the data looks like:

```
var menu1 =
[{
    text: "Company Name",
    cssClass: "ob-blue",
 }, 
 {
    text: "Customer's Name",
    cssClass: "light",
    items: [
       { text: "Mike Hunt" },
       { text: "Ben Dover" },
       { text: "Harry Cox" },
       { text: "Jack Goff" }
     ]
}, 
{
    text: "Color",
    cssClass: "dark",
    items: [
       { text: "Black" },
       { text: "White" },
       { text: "Blue" },
       { text: "Red" }
    ]
}, 
{
    text: "Prices",
    cssClass: "light",
    items: [
      { text: "$20,000" },
      { text: "$50,000" },
      { text: "$100,000" },
      { text: "150,000" }
    ]
}, 
{
    text: "Brand",
    cssClass: "dark",
    items: [
       { text: "Ford" },
       { text: "Chevrolet" },
       { text: "Audi" },
       { text: "Honda" }
     ]
}, 
{
    text: "Year",
    cssClass: "light",
    items: [
       { text: "2008" },
       { text: "2012" },
       { text: "2013" },
       { text: "2014" }
    ]
}, 
{
    text: "Miles",
    cssClass: "dark",
    items: [
       { text: "10" },
       { text: "10,000" },
       { text: "45,000" },
       { text: "80,000" }
]
}];
```

The link below provides some helpful documentation with the Kendo DataSource:

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/getting-started/framework/datasource/overview